# Set Magento Cookie Variable Using jQuery click() event

Tags: magento-1.7, cookie

I am in the process of trying to set a Magento cookie variable on click using jQuery but can't seem to get it too work.

Would the best way to do this be to hit a controller action using ajax when the click event is fired and then use the following code snippet inside the controller action?

```
Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->set($name, $value);
```

Or is this approach a complex way of doing such a task and is there a different approach I should take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought cookies could be set on the frontend?

Here is how you could store the store code using 'standard' Magento methods:

```
    var urlStoreCode = window.location.pathname.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g,"").split('/')[0];
    if(urlStoreCode != "") Mage.Cookies.set('store', urlStoreCode);
```

That uses the Magento library and I don't see why jQuery is needed when there is an adequate library built in. Doing it this way means there is no need to create work for the server.

What did I miss?